# Hide bootstrap 3 columns when past 12

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col 1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col 2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col 3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col 4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col 5</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col 6</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col 7</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col 8</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col 9</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col A</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col B</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col C</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col D</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col E</div>
</div>
```

I want to see:

- 12 columns when screen `1200px < width` -- Col 1 through Col B
- 6 columns when `992px < width < 1200px` -- Col 1 through Col 6, and
- 4 columns when `768px < width < 992px` -- Col 1 through Col 4

and for all the other columns to be hidden automatically based on the screen width and the col-[sm|md|lg] setting. Is there a way to enable this via css only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can custom a little bit with css query using ntn css

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
  .row-filter .col-sm-3:nth-child(n + 5){
    display: none;
  }
  
}


@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .row-filter .col-md-2:nth-child(n + 7){
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .row-filter .col-lg-1:nth-child(n + 13){
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row row-filter">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col 1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col 2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col 3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col 4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col 5</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col 6</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col 7</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col 8</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col 9</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col A</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col B</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col C</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col D</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">Col E</div>
</div>
```

See the codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvPJOY

Comment: That looks like what I need. I am going to try it out now. Thank you.

Comment: Nice to help you :)

Comment: How can I extend this to hide the first visible <div> and unhide the first hidden <div> in either direction in combination with a left and right button and javascript/onclick handler?

Comment: @Vishal: Just use javascript add class to hide and show

Comment: Wont the nth-child {} hide the <div> that should be unhidden?

Comment: @Vishal: yes. You should add class to override `ntn-child` css style